# Mean interval estimation when data are not binomial

Tags: confidence-interval, mean

When a set of data are binomial I have a lot of methods available to me (Wilson score interval, Wilson score interval with continuity correction, Jeffreys interval, Clopper-Pearson interval, Agresti-Coull Interval) other than the standard Wald interval estimation method (see  Interval Estimation for a Binomial Proportion Author(s): Lawrence D. Brown, T. Tony Cai and Anirban DasGupta).

However, I can't use these methods for data that is itself proportional in the sense of it sitting in [0,1].

For example consider a sample of n respondents, giving a score for a question X as:

```
r_1 = 0.4
r_2 = 0.3
...
r_n = 0.2
```

How would I calculate the confidence interval for a mean based on this data? Is there any way other than bootstrapping?

Comment: Do you mean that the response to the question must lie between $0$ and $1$? Also, how large is the sample? If it's big enough (practically speaking $>30$ with a reasonable range of answers), asymptotics should allow you calculate it on something approaching normal...

Comment: Yes it lies between 0 and 100 or 0 and 1 rather. The sample size is variable, we decided to only consider >30. For less than 30 we have considered a bootstrap.

Comment: I am wary of the CLT confidence interval interval for growing sample size - the paper above showed that the coverage probability varies greatly away from the nominal confidence level as n grows. So I'm really interested in a mean confidence interval method for non binomial data (apart from CLT CI).

Comment: You don't have bimomial data. You have discrete data on a scale of 0-100. Any scenario you think of for the actual population will have the sample means behaving like a normal distribution for n>30. You should run some simulations on your own to convince yourself.

Comment: Your answer echoes the very title: the O.P. says these are indeed not binomial.  How, then, does this reply address his question about calculating a CI for the mean?

Comment: Sorry for the pun, but statistics is always a bit of a 'guessing game.  If his responses come back strange, heavy proportion voting 100, and a small frequency voting 0, then his data would actually be similar to binomial, and he'd run into the problem of the binomial check of N*p being less than 5.  Any other scenario, and his data behaves normally.

Comment: I've run a lot of simulations on discrete data having weird distributions.

Comment: (Sorry for the comment deletion -- your previous comment to it appeared as I finished typing mine and I didn't see it for a while, and deleted it because I wanted to respond to that instead -- but your subsequent comment didn't show for me until after I deleted mine. Apologies!)  Your comment falls into a logical fallacy; "I have tried everything I could think of and it didn't happen" isn't evidence that it can't happen, only that you failed to think of a situation where it can. For example, consider a distribution that has 97% chance of 0 and 1% chance for each of 1, 50, and 100. Not binomial

Comment: Yet sample means for $n=30, 31, 32...$ don't look normal to me.

Comment: [Here's](http://i.imgur.com/jqOhhY6.png) a simulation of sample means for n=50. Not binomial, but the means are not normal.

Comment: I would consider that 'pretty close to binomial'.And, for what it's worth, we will get a pretty accurate estimate of the mean quite quickly in that scenario.The problem with your point about the logical fallacy is that as long as I've tried the extreme situations, I've covered everything.  Sort of like when we're estimating the sample size required for a binomial proportion, we just assume p = .5, because that's the scenario with the highest variance. Do you think, I sat there and played around with only a trivial scenario?  Here I am commenting on this site, and the assumption is I am stupid?

Comment: Glen, thanks for that graph, but I don't understand it.  What is the assumed population?  Is it the 0,1,50, 100 you mentioned?  Why do you have multiple frequencies at each interval?

Comment: Hi, "pretty close" & "pretty accurate" seems like (forgive me) hand-wavy statistics. If there is a proof of correctness for this, I'll take it more seriously. Right now these comments feel like they might be appropriate for a separate discussion. Sara I am going to flag your comments. I feel that you are taking criticism too personally - and I am no where closer to an answer for it.

Comment: Go for it.  My ultimate recommendation for you is that you get your hands dirty yourself.